# adjective to describe a video device with a lot of functionality

Tags: word-choice, adjectives

What's the right adjective to describe a video device like a camcorder or VCR that has a lot of functionality?

For example,

> Wow! this camcorder/VCR is quite ________________ !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really need an adjective, you could go with something like "full-featured" or "feature-rich." But more likely, the way a native speaker would say that is "Wow! This camcorder has a lot of features!"

Answer (score 0):

**Multifunctional** - having or able to perform many functions:

> Wow! This camcorder is multifunctional! *(I'd avoid "quite")*